# Can someone explain the double te form?

Tags: grammar, て-form

I was reading an article on NHK and I came across this

> こうした歴史から、同じソビエトを構成した国のなかでも、ロシアはウクライナに対して特に“同じルーツを持つ国”という意識を強く**持っていている**と指摘しています。[for full context](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20220228/k10013504991000.html#:%7E:text=%E6%84%8F%E8%AD%98%E3%82%92%E5%BC%B7%E3%81%8F-,%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B,-%E3%81%A8%E6%8C%87%E6%91%98%E3%81%97)

Can someone explain the usage of double te form here? I've also seen triple te form once or twice before.

Comment: Must be a typo.

Comment: Agreed, it should be just "持っている".